# How do I add a new item to this menu on the Add New Page section?

Tags: pages

This menu has 5 items: `All, Mine, Published, Draft, Trash`

[image]

I want to add a new one `FrontPage`, in red, that will list pages with specific `ID`, like 43, 32, 11, 344, etc.

If the answer is complex, just point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more, not entirely sure what you're asking.  How would this new 'Front Page' filter know which pages to display under it?

Comment: How Mine, Published, etc. knows which pages to open? My idea is by page ID. I specify, let's say 5 page ids and a little PHP magic runs the show.